# How to customize icon of expo push notifications?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm sending push notifications to an expo app, and I would like to customize the icon of the notification. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

It can be set in `app.json` in `Expo`.

**"notification"**

Configuration for remote (push) notifications.

```json
{
   "expo":{
      "name":"firstApp",
      "description":"firstApp",
      "slug":"firstApp",
      "privacy":"public",
      "sdkVersion":"31.0.0",
      "notification":{
         "icon":"./assets/images/iconPushNotification.png"
      },
      "ios":{
         "bundleIdentifier":"com.firstApp.firstApp"
      },
      "android":{
         "package":"com.firstApp.firstApp",
         "versionCode":1,
         "permissions":[
            ""
         ]
      },
      "platforms":[
         "ios",
         "android"
      ],
      "version":"1.0.0",
      "orientation":"portrait",
      "icon":"./assets/images/robot-prod.png"
   }
}
```

**If your app is a stand-alone app,(use Expokit)**

> **ExpoKit**: To change the notification icon, edit or replace the
> shell_notification_icon.png files in
> android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-. On iOS, notification
> icons are the same as the app icon. All other properties are set at
> runtime.

Comment: I already did that but it does not work, and in addition I also did something in api
{
"to" => $ tokenOfMobile,
"title" => $ message ['title'],
"Icon" => $ path
}
nothing has changed

Comment: {
  "expo": {
    "name": "firstApp",
    "description": "firstApp",
    "slug": "firstApp",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/iconPushNotification.png"
    },
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.firstApp.firstApp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.firstApp.firstApp",
      "versionCode":1 ,
      "permissions":[""]
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/robot-prod.png",
}

Comment: @zakitutu Please edit and post the questions so that you can see them

Comment: @zakitutu was this happening because u were in dev mode? Currently I am experiencing same problem but I haven't test this in production

Comment: @zakitutu did you find a way to get the right icon for push notifications on iOS? Having same issue.

Comment: Having this issue with iOS, I publish the app to Test Flight and icon show is the expo icon.